# Save certificate included in phonegap / cordova app distribution

Tags: ios, cordova, certificate

I need to have my users install a root CA certificate which is included in my Phonegap app (just like you would include your images or javascript files). I am able to link to the file like a standard embedded image. For example:

```
<!-- this is an image included in the phonegap app -->
<img src="img/mylogo.png" />

<!-- this is the certificate also included in the phonegap app -->
<a href="cert/mycacert.cer">My Cert</a>
```

When I open the app on iOS and click the link to the embedded cert, nothing happens. My goal is to have iOS prompt to install the certificate. Is there a better way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I was unable to get this to work. I tried FileTransfer with a relative path to the resource and a plain vanilla link, neither of which worked.

I ended up hosting the certificate on a SSL protected domain for download. For the download I used `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` and the following code:

`window.open('https://thesite.com/thecert.cer', '_server')`

The DL starts and prompts to install as expected.